# Pending Intent Passing String Result Not Got

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to pass String from one activity to another.
I read how it is done but when I am implementing I am not able to get the required output.

My first class:

```
public class Settings extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {


private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.setting);
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(Settings.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent.putExtra("key", "Tuesday");
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Settings.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
    alarmRepeat();
}
  public void alarmRepeat(){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000, pendingIntent);
}
```

My 2nd Activity where I have passed "key" String :

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

AudioManager audioControl;
Bundle extras;
String days;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    Date d = new Date();
    String day = sdf.format(d);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    audioControl = (AudioManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    days = intent.getStringExtra("key");
    if(day.equals("days")){audioControl.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);}
}
```

According to the program the audio setting of the phone should be changed to vibration, but nothing happens.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing here. If you want to check if `day` is `Tuesday`, change `if (day.equals("days"))` to `if (day.equals(days))`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your code. Your last line should be if(day.equals(**days**)) { ...
Debuggers will also help you analyze why an equality test isn't triggering.
Corrected code below:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    Date d = new Date();
    String day = sdf.format(d);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    audioControl = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    days = intent.getStringExtra("key");
    if(day.equals(days) {audioControl.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);}
}
```